# How can I build this XML structure in JSON through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, .net, xml, json, json.net

I have this XML structure that I wish to construct in JSON format using JavaScript - **preferably using dot notation all the way if possible. :)**

Here is the XML - note this is a pseudo structure, to keep it simple! :)

```
<Items>
   <Item>
      <Name>Item 1</Name>
      <SubItems>
         <Item>
           <Name>Sub Item 1</Name>
         </Item>
      </SubItems>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Item 2</Name>
   </Item>
</Items>
```

So, when I convert my JSON to XML (on the server), the output should be like above.

I need help getting started with this. I Google'd around and I couldn't find any examples on how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am using NewtonSoft JSON for .NET to convert from JSON to XML!

**EDIT 2: Ok, I figured out the Raw JSON structure to get the convertion to XML right - here it is:**

```
var json = {
        "Items":
            {
                "Item":
                    [   
                        {
                            "Name": "Test 1" ,
                            "SubItems":
                            {
                                "Item":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "Name":"Test 1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Name":"Test 2"
                                        }
                                    ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Name":"Test 2"
                        }
                    ]
            }
    };
```

That will produce the exact same XML structure as defined above.

Now, how would I go about building this structure using **dot notation?**

EDIT 3: With the help of Nikhil & Darin, I figured it out, however this only answers the pseudo-question. However I will mark this as answered and create a new question. :)

EDIT 4: I posted my extension to the marked answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json = {};
json.Items = {};
json.Items.Item = new Array();

var item1 = {};
item1.Name = "Test 1"
item1.SubItems = new Array();

var subItem1 = {};
subItem1.Item = new Array();
subSubItem1 = {};
subSubItem1.Name = "Test 1";
subSubItem2 = {};
subSubItem2.Name = "Test 2";
subItem1.Item.push(subSubItem1);
subItem1.Item.push(subSubItem2);
item1.SubItems.push(subItem1);
var item2 = {};
item2.Name = "Test 2";
json.Items.Item.push(item1);
json.Items.Item.push(item2);
```

Output of the above code is

```
{
    "Items": {
        "Item": [
            {
                "Name": "Test 1",
                "SubItems": [
                    {
                        "Item": [
                            {
                                "Name": "Test 1"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Test 2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "Test 2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

that should do it :)

Comment: Ahh just saw your edit. NOW I know what you meant by dynamic ;) Well my code here is actually static. But I hope it helps!

Comment: Accepted, as this DOES answer the question that was asked. :)

Comment: In case you are interested, I posted my complete answer, however yours stays marked as the answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

this should do it:

```
var items = [
              {"name":"Item 1","subitems":[
                {"name":"Subitem 1"}
              ]},
              {"name":"Item 2"}
            ];
```

Comment: you would fetch a particular item's name by calling `items[i].name`, where `i` is the item's index. Similarly, subitems' names may be fetched with `items[i].subitems[j].name`

Comment: And this will generate the exact same XML structure when converted? So, <Item> wont be <0> and <1>?

Comment: It all depends on your server. If you're using something like Ruby on Rails for instance, you can render an object either as XML or as JSON, and you don't have to worry about how exactly the render works. In order to understand your issue better I'd have to see server-side code.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't fully understand. Do you want to convert a JSON object into XML using Javascript? Initial google results lead me to [this handy jQuery plugin](http://michalkorecki.com/content/introducing-json-xml-jquery-plugin)

Comment: I am using NewtonSoft JSON to convert JSON to XML - I wish to send the JSON string to the server, and convert it to XML there. However it is very important that the output structure is exactly as specified in the XML example. :)

Comment: Ah. I'm not familiar with NewtonSoft. If I may ask, why are you passing XML back to the server? JSON is a much lighter format, and front-end conversions are usually hackier than back-end.

Comment: @Jeff : The above structure is perfectly valid. The only way to check if it works with NewtonSoft is to actually try it :)

Comment: Spencer, I am not passing XML to the server, I am passing JSON to the server, and CONVERTING it to XML on the server. :)) - @NikhilPatil , yes, it may be valid, but it may not produce the wanted output when converted ;) Please see my latest edit, I posted a valid JSON structure (I figured it out,however my question is not fully answered yet ;) )

Comment: @Jeff: Cheers! and about your question being answered, actually, it is! @Darin's answer above will produce the same JSON. However, you'll have to add one more step at the end to his code to get the items array as an attribute of var json i.e. `var json = {}; json.Items = items;`

Comment: @NikhilPatil - But will it also produce the <Item> node for each item?:)

Comment: @NikhilPatil - Just tested, and as I suspected, it doesen't. So no, it has not been fully answered yet :)

Comment: @Jeff : Umm sorry should have noted this earlier, but are you sure this JSON is valid? Cause in your XML the node `<Items>` holds multiple `<Item>` children. So its corresponding json element should be an array whereas in your json `Items` is actually an object! And secondly, in your XML the node `<Item>` has single `<Name>` node. Whereas your JSON shows that `Item` as an array!

Comment: @NikhilPatil Yes, in fact my JSON is the only thing that converts without failing, AND I get the expected output. What I am looking for, is a dynamic way (is that the correct term?) of generating my JSON structure, using Dot Notation :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = [ ];

var item1 = { };
item1.Name = 'Item 1';
item1.SubItems = [ ];
var subItem = { };
subItem.Name = 'Sub Item 1';
item1.SubItems.push(subItem);
items.push(item1);

var item2 = { };
item2.Name = 'Item 2';
items.push(item2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nikhil answered the question, and has gotten the magic tick. :) - I am extending his answer with the code I wrote to get the result I was looking for.

My real problem, after receiving the answer to the pseudo problem, was that I have different item **types** in my structure, which all shared the Items root node.

Here is a pseudo example of how I solved the issue. Again, Nikhil's answer was the base of the solution, so many thanks to him :)

Say we have a rootnode, Fruits, and we have different types of fruit. Say, apple, and banana.

Here's how I got the JSON structure (and ultimately, the XML convertion output that I was needing):

```
// Create the JSON Object
var json = {};
// Create the Fruits Objects (Our root)
json.Fruits = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
    // Pseudo condition
    if (i == 0 || i == 1) {
        // Make sure we have an Apple array
        if(json.Fruits.Apple == undefined)
            json.Fruits.Apple = [];
        json.Fruits.Apple.push({
             "Color": "Green"
        });
     } else {
        // Make sure we have a Banana array
        if (json.Fruits.Banana == undefined)
            json.Fruits.Banana = [];
        json.Fruits.Banana.push({
             "Color": "Yellow" 
        });
    }
}
```

This will output the following JSON:

```
{"Fruits":
   {"Apple":
      [
       {"Color":"Green"},
       {"Color":"Green"}
      ],
    "Banana":
      [
       {"Color":"Yellow"}
      ]
   }
}
```

And ultimately, the following XML:

```
<Fruits>
  <Apple>
    <Color>Green</Color> 
  </Apple>
  <Apple>
    <Color>Green</Color> 
  </Apple>
  <Banana>
    <Color>Yellow</Color> 
  </Banana>
</Fruits>
```